# Posting a javascript variable into a text area using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea

I am using PHP to post into a `textarea`:

```
<textarea name="">
<?php echo $name?>
</textarea>
```

---

I have tried to do this.

Jquery:

```
var yo = "Hello"
$.post(window.location, {variable: yo});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['variable'];
?>
```

Why does this not write "Hello" in the `textarea` / Why is the php not receiving the .post?

Comment: everything is hazy here, what is your actual problem ? - what is your goal?

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: why it should work :)?

Comment: because its an ajax request, your page is not reloaded

Comment: @MamaWalter ask you: why it should work? it is fundamentally incorrect approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>` as URL at your jQuery post function instead of `window.location` as follow

```
$.post(<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>, {variable: yo});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change a value inside a `textarea` with a value you calculate or set in javascript, you can assign it this way using JQuery:

```
<script>
var yo = "hello";
$("#test").html(yo); //where test is the ID from the textarea
</script>

<textarea id="test">
</textarea>
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/YcgsR/

Comment: I actually have other stuff inside the `textarea` so so I can't just replace the html

Comment: do you want to append content to the textarea or you want to post the data from the textarea? or both?

Comment: Basically it is a load of html inside written like this inside `&lt;table width="703" border="0" align="center">
    &lt;tr>` and I am wanting to write a javascript variable inside. But I can only seem to write php variables

Comment: your comment raises even more questions, please update your question with more details of what is your goal

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your logic a bit here by making your PHP script take in your JS variable and do some logic/manipulation/query/whatever (that you *can't* do via JS) and return a value which you want to appear in the textarea. You can then leverage this return value via an AJAX request like so:

```
var yo = "Hello";
$.post(window.location, {variable: yo}, function(value) {
    $('textarea').val(value);
});
```

and in your PHP script, something like:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['variable'];
    /*
     * do manipulation here that you can't do purely via JS
     * otherwise why would you be posting to a PHP script?
     */
    echo $some_return_value;
?>
```